# R Shiny selectize selected event

Tags: r, shiny

When using selectize in R Shiny, is it possible to capture the currently highlighted element in the selection box? From the [gallery](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-examples.html):

```
selectizeInput(
    'e2', '2. Multi-select', choices = state.name, multiple = TRUE
  )
```

If after selecting a few States, one then clicked on 'California':

[image: selectize selection]

Is is possible to the selection of 'California' captured?  Use case is to trigger a filter on a datatable so that it shows only information for the selected State.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom JavaScript render.item method (not really pretty in one character string) :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = 'select',
    label = '2. Multi-select',
    choices = state.name, 
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = list(
      render = I("{item: function(item, escape) {return '<div class=\"item\" onclick=\"Shiny.onInputChange(\\\'select_click\\\', \\\'' + escape(item.value) + '\\\')\">' + escape(item.value) + '</div>';}}")
    )
  ),
  tags$p("Selected:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("res_select"),
  tags$p("Click:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("res_click")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res_select <- renderPrint({
    input$select
  })
  output$res_click <- renderPrint({
    input$select_click
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks so much that's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
if it is to trigger a filter you would have to use it as an output to ( call it here )

```
 data1 <- <nameofyourfile>

 <dashboardbody options>.. .

column(2,selectizeInput('e2', '2. Multi-select', 
choices = state.name, multiple = TRUE)),uiOutput("StateOutput")
```

and this part goes in the server :

```
    output$StateOutput <- renderUI({ 
    data1 %>% filter(data1$<variablename> == input$e2Input)
    <insert the kind of filter you want to show based on the new data1>
                  })
```

Comment: This isnt what he wants, he needs an event capture trigger once the selection is highlights, blue